# How to push using SVN in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, svn

I'm using SVN to sub-versioning in Eclipse. I can update and do commit as well, but I'm not finding where I can do a push to the remote branch.

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`svn commit` pushes your changes to the remote server. There is no distinction between `commit` and `push` in SVN, as you don't have local repositories there like in Git. Therefore, you are only talking to one repository, which is the remote one.

Comment: It's correct that there's no distinction between commit and push for SVN, but I'd say the reason is that there's no local copy of the repository for SVN.  A GIT commit updates changes to local repo; push commits them to remote server.

Comment: Thanks for the input, I edited my answer slightly to make that aspect clearer.